# Anaconda can't make a environment. Its seems like making trouble with finding python

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

Sorry for bothering you guys with a silly problems.

I need a help for making environment with Anaconda3.

I just try to make it with python version 3.7, but it makes an error message just like this.

```
(base) C:\Users\user\Workspace>conda create -n keras python=3.7  

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - python=3.7
```

Even trying to make environment with python version 3.9 doesn't work.

But when I find a python by looking for its version, it says that python is well placing inside.

```
(base) C:\Users\user\Workspace>python -V
Python 3.9.12
```

'where python' and 'conda list' also shows that python is well installed.

```
(base) C:\Users\user\Workspace>where python
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

(base) C:\Users\user\Workspace>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\user\anaconda3:
...
pytest                    7.1.1            py39haa95532_0
python                    3.9.12               h6244533_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.15.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
...
```

Version of anaconda and any other else are perfectly latest version. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What is the Operative System have installed in your environment?
Are you installed python3.7?

The first download python 3.7 from next link windows https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/python-3.7.9-amd64.exe

Next create a new enviroment 3.7
virtualenv C:\Users<your_username>\Anaconda3\envs<env_name> -p C:<some_path>\Python37\python.exe

Comment: Making environment with no python works well... but it doesn't solve the problem :( "conda search '*python*' " also returns nothing.

Comment: "conda install python=3.7" doesn't work also.